# matlab what is code segment calculating?

Tags: matlab

I have being trying to figure out what some matlab code is doing. It takes three data points with X and corresponding Y values:

X
,Y

and does a fit:

```
fy = polyfit(X, Y, 2)
```

which is a second order fit of the three X, Y data points.

Then this is followed by this line of code:

```
U = -fy(2) / (2*fy(1))
```

This seems to calculate an X value in the range between X(1) and X(3) but I'm not sure what it is exactly calculating? Why is it multiplying the fy(1) value by 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fy(1)` is the coefficient of the `x^2` term, and `fy(2)` is the coefficient for the `x` term.  The `2*` makes me think derivative, so let's see what that looks like.  First the original quadratic fit:

```
fy(1)*x^2 + fy(2)*x + fy(3)
```

Now the derivative:

```
2*fy(1)*x + fy(2)
```

Ahah, starting to look familiar.  What about setting equal to zero and solving for x?

```
2*fy(1)*x + fy(2) = 0
2*fy(1)*x = -fy(2)
x = -fy(2) / (2*fy(1))
```

Yep, that's it.  So it's computing the x location where the derivative of the quadratic fit equals zero.  And what happens at the place where the first derivative of a curve equals zero?  A maximum or a minimum.

So, this code finds the x coordinate of the max or min of the quadratic fit of the data.  An accurate peak finder?

Comment: Hi Peter. That's all exactly right. Thank you!...and yes the code is used to find the peak in a dataset.